# Qt signal slot over thread, is this the safe way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtcore, qt-signals

Say, I have 2 threads: A and B, A is the main thread. In thread A, there are two on_button_click slots. The first one is:

```
on_button_one_clicked(){
  myObject_one = new myObject(this);
  myObject_one->setParent(map);
  myObject_two = new myObject(this);
  myObject_two->setParent(map);
  ...
}
```

The second one is:

```
on_button_two_clicked(){
  foreach(myObject* i, map->childItems){
    delete i;
  }
}
```

Here, *myObject* and *map* are all `QGraphicsItem`s. In thread B, a signal is emitted to trigger a slot of thread A:

```
slot_triggered_by_signal_from_thread_B(){
  foreach(myObject* i, map->childItems){
    i->do_some_thing();
  }
}
```

Is this safe? Will it happen, when the codes comes to the line *i->do_some_thing* and meet an empty pointer and crash?

Comment: Keep all UI stuff always happening in the main thread, you should only offload heavy calculations which take a lot of time to another thread. And by "a lot of time" I mean at least 50 milliseconds or more.

Comment: Yes, but what you are saying is exactly what I am doing now, i->do_some_thing() is in the main thread already.

Comment: If you are doing the work in the main thread, why bother using another thread at all? The purpose of using extra threads is to keep the main thread responsive. And also, if that is the case, this sounds like you have moved interaction with the UI in the other thread, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @ddriver: I think do_some_thing() is UI related and he has heavy computation in another thread that e.g. when finished triggers UI action. Looks sane to me what the OP did in that regard. What he is asking is whether it is ok to do something on QGIs that may be deleted "simultaneously".

Comment: @lpapp - what would that heavy computation be? That would mean he is using the UI representation for data and logic, which is wrong by design as data and logic should be abstracted away and only linked to the UI to be represented.

Comment: @lpapp - my logic is simple - there should be nothing akin of "heavy computation" in the UI whatsoever, that should be another design layer.

Comment: @ddriver: the OP has never claimed heavy computation in the main thread in my understanding. That is the whole point why the worker thread is signalling when e.g. done. I still do not understand your problem. I think the question is legit and so I even gave an upvote now.

Comment: @lpapp - it doesn't matter in which thread it is, it matters if it is encapsulated within the UI representation, which spells "bad design". As I already said, it should be another layer in the application design, then multithreading will not be concerned with the UI whatsoever.

Comment: @ddriver: I cannot claim that I follow you. If you do the heavy computation in thread B as the OP does, and e.g. when that is ready, it is *completely* valid to update the QGI UI based on the result of the computation. This is kind of the whole point of Qt GUI applications with QThreads, really when the computation affects the UI.

Comment: `Here,myObject and map are all QGraphicsItem. In thread B, it will emit a signal to trigger a slot in thread A` sounds like it is the item which lives in the main thread is what's emitting a signal in thread B to be executed in the main. I don't see any notion of heavy computation only being triggered by the item in another thread in that question.

Comment: @Nyaruko you should produce a minimal WORKING example, because right now I think lpapp is seeing Jesus in the burn pattern of a toast :)

Comment: He provided a completely minimal example that makes the confusion clear. It is unfortunate that you do not see it, but the valid question is there. Just move on.

Comment: @ddriver, I think lpapp got me right. I thought this should be a simple short question though..

Comment: @Nyaruko - if you feel like he helped you then it is all good.

Comment: @ddriver: just for _your_ sake, I created a simple example reproducing the conceptual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe as long as you use the auto connection or queued conncetion type between the threads since then the slot will be only invoked when your other slot is finishing up or vice versa. They will not be running "simultaneously". That is the only concern that I could imagine for this not to be safe enough. I believe you meant a scenario like this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>

class Work : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Work(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent) { QTimer::singleShot(200, this, SLOT(mySlot())); }
    public slots:
        void mySlot() { emit mySignal(); }
    signals:
        void mySignal();
};

class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:

    explicit MyApplication(int argc, char **argv)
        : QApplication(argc, argv)
        , pushButton(new QPushButton())
    {
        QStringList stringList{"foo", "bar", "baz"};
        QThread *workerThread = new QThread();

        Work *work = new Work();
        work->moveToThread(workerThread);

        connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [&stringList] () {
            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); ++i)
                stringList.removeAt(i);
        });
        connect(work, &Work::mySignal, [&stringList] () {
            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); ++i)
                qDebug() << stringList.at(i);           
        });
    }

    ~MyApplication()
    {
        delete pushButton;
    }

    QPushButton *pushButton;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyApplication application(argc, argv);   
    return application.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

Comment: But if he emits other async signals for each item, it could very well end up a major performance bottleneck, queued signals are slow, especially when the event loop becomes clogged with them. A few years back I actually got a huge performance drop from using finely grained workers with queued signals.

Comment: Is Qt::UniqueConnection Ok to be used here? Will it cause the running to be "simultaneously"?

Comment: @Nyaruko: as [the documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) writes, it is used to avoid multiple connections between the same sender's same signal and the same receiver's same slot. In short, that is irrelevant to your problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that main thread does some heavy work in `on_button_two_clicked` function.
Any other actions include user do something or another request from other thread 
(in this case `slot_triggered_by_signal_from_thread_B`) will be blocked until
finishing `on_button_two_clicked`.

I think it means that it guarantees finishing previous event.
In conclusion, it is safe!

Comment: You misunderstood the OP IMHO. He is not doing the heavy work in the main thread, that is the whole point of the question. He is doing the main work in the _non_-main-thread, and he is just signalling back to the main thread to do some GUI work, e.g. when the heavy work is done.

Comment: @lpapp - are you sure? Read his first (the second) comment on the question.

Comment: @ddriver: `Keep all UI stuff always happening in the main thread` -> `Yes, but what you are saying is exactly what I am doing now, i->do_some_thing() is in the main thread already`. I think you misunderstood the situation and perhaps misled parivana, too. :/ Anyway, I would remove this answer since it writes about a different scenario than what the OP has.

Comment: @lpapp He says `do_some_thing()` is happening in the main thread. I don't see anything else that might look like "heavy computation that might need offloading" besides `do_some_thing()`. So it runs in the main thread, and how is this "not doing the heavy work in the main thread"? Me thinks the OP has a problem with his design, and what you think you understand in his question is some augmented version of it. The details of his question don't really make sense and overall spell confusion.

Comment: @ddriver: It is really very very simple, he has two threads: main and worker, main emits a signal and so a slot gets called that deletes things and the worker thread signals back to the main thread when e.g. done, and that operates on the GUI items, too. He asks whether this is safe.

Comment: I think OP just worry about referring object in `slot_triggered_by_signal_from_thread_B` while deleting in `on_button_two_clicked`. This post is just thread safe, not a heavy work or UI things.

Comment: @parivana - it sounds to me the OP has a case of bad design. So while some might see the reassurance that the bad design is safe as a sufficient enough answer, I cannot help but feel like the answer he needs is how to improve his design.

Comment: @lpapp I think you should stop insinuating. About the question, about what I need to learn and so on. I know what threads are used for, but you don't seem to know a lot about elegant and flexible application design. Too busy repping up on addressing minor technicalities mayhaps?